# error al ejecutar el programa de c++

Tags: dev-c++

> El problema es que la billetera cuando llegue a 0 el programa se debe cerrar y en mi caso el programa no se cierra si no que descuenta por ejemplo tengo 500 en la billetera apuesto los 500 y pierdo no pasa nada hasta pudo seguir apostando y los tira en -100 por ejemplo y eso no debe pasar.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;
void juego(){
int n, Bill, v, cont=0, acv, acbill;
bool corrcnum=false;
char resp='s';
int num = 1 + rand()%(20-1);
cout<<"Adivina el numero generado \n";
cout<<"\nIndique el valor de su billetera electronica: \n";
cin>>Bill;
while(resp=='s' && Bill>0 && corrcnum==false){
cont++; 

cout<<"\ncuanto desea apostar: \n";
cin>>v;
cout<<"\nIngresa un numero entre 1 y 20:  \n";
cin>>n;

if(n>num) {
cout<<"\nPerdiste, tu numero es mayor que el numero generado\n";
Bill=Bill-v;
}
else if(n<num){
cout<<"\nPerdiste, tu numero es menor que el numero generado\n";
Bill=Bill-v;
}   
else {
corrcnum=true;
    cout<<"\nAdivinaste\n";
    acv=(v*2);
    Bill=acv+Bill;
}

    cout<<"Quieres seguir jugando:  Si=s  No=n  \n";
    cin>>resp;
```

> /*Hay un margen de error aqui porque al compilar, cuando el usuario adivina o cuando la
> billetera queda en 0
> el programa siempre hace la pregunta "quiere seguir jugando", al responder esa pregunta ya
> aparece que cuantas
> veces jugo o que la billetera queda en 0. No pude corregir ese detalle, no encontré como*/

```
}
if (corrcnum=true){
    cout<<"\nnumero de veces que jugaste: \n"; cout<<cont;
    cout<<"\ntu billetera quedo en: \n"; cout<<Bill;
    cout<<"\nEl numero generado fue:  ";cout<<num;
}

  }


 int main(){

srand(time(NULL));
juego ();
        
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has intentado hacer la comparación así

```
if (corrcnum=true)
```

Esta condición siempre es cierta y además asigna **true** a **corrnum**. Deberías haberlo hecho así

```
if (corrcnum == true)
```

con doble igual, o mejor aún, así

```
if (corrcnum)
```

y evitas problemas.

Por otro lado, podrías mejorar el programa comprobando si la cantidad apostada es mayor al valor de la billetera.

Comment: muchas gracias, quizas por el agobio que tenia no miraba esa falla.

Comment: Es un error muy común en C y en Javascript que usan == para la comparación. Yo llevo muchos años en esto y aún lo cometo.